# php variable to google charts api no JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to pass a few PHP variables into a Google Chart, and I cannot seem to get the syntax right.  I don't want to invoke JSON (need I?).

Stock example: This works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Number');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Frequency');
    data.addRows([
            ['Mushrooms', 3],
            ['Onions', 1],
            ['Olives', 1], 
            ['Zucchini', 1],
            ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);
        var options = {
            'title':'Title',
            'width':400,
            'height':300
        };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

However, this does not (assume all the same surrounding code)

```
  function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Number');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Frequency');
     data.addRows([
    ['Mushrooms', <?php echo $phpvariable ?>],
    ['Onions', 1],
    ['Olives', 1], 
    ['Zucchini', 1],
    ['Pepperoni', 2]
  ]);
```

My thoughts:
Positioning of the calculation of `$phpvariable` is wrong? or do I just need to use JSON somehow, and PHP variables cannot be passed?

Comment: As long as you have set `$phpvariable` before you try and echo it this should work absolutely fine.

Comment: Thank you so much. $phpvariable had to be calculated before. 
It didn't occur, as I didn't know if it were bad practice to perform calculations in the <head>.
Obliged.

Comment: Personally I put most of my php code before the first HTML tag!

Comment: How interesting. Is there a benefit? Or is it personal preference?

Comment: In my opinion the benefit is all your PHP (or at least the vast majority) is above your HTML, easier to maintain. The PHP that is in the HTML is then pretty much just simple ifs and foreach loops, not huge logical chunks. It is a preference but I stick to it :)

Comment: Your insight is appreciated